# Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am currently setting my server side with `NodeJS`, `ExpressJS`, `Sequelize` and `PostgresSQL`

i have my code set up as follows:-

in my `config/config.js` file i have the folowing

```
username: "Eexpress-mvp-dbuser",
    password: "123",
    database: "mvp-db",
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    dialect: "postgress",
    port: 5432,
    operatorsAliases: false
```

in my migrations file i have the following code set up

````
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable("Leads", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("Leads");
  }
};```

Sequelize CLI [Node: 8.11.3, CLI: 5.5.0, ORM: 5.12.3]

Loaded configuration file "config\config.js".

ERROR: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0
````

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the dialect name :

Use `dialect: "postgres"`

instead of `dialect: "postgress"`

Also be sure to install the following dependencies :

```
npm install pg --save
npm install pg-hstore --save
```

And finally, you need to create a database. Sequelize doesn't make it for you